# Drop down menu vertical 3 level

Tags: html, css

Vertical drop down menu, It has a bug in the last list item

```
<div class="geral">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">categoria</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">nivel 1</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">nivel 2</a>
          <ul style="background: #f00;">
            <li><a href="#">nivel  2.1</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">Level 2.2</a>
              <ul style="background: #0f0;">
                <li><a href="#">Level 2.1.1</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#">Level 2.1.2</a>
                  <ul style="background: #00f;">
                    <li><a href="#">Level 2.1.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Level 2.1.1.2</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Level 2.1.3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Link to demo with bug: https://jsfiddle.net/joseferreira/z4j8dfbt/

Comment: Is it a bug because it collapses when you try to hover over Level 2.1.3?  I think this is happening because as you 'leave' Level 2.1.1.2 that level of menus collapse - at which point your menu has shortened in size and where Level 2.1.3 was, has now moved up.  Since that also means you left the menu entirely, it collapses the entire thing believing you are now somewhere else in the page.  I don't know how you should fix this, but the menu as it stands behaves in a way I would expect it to.